# How to connect to SFTP server using ssh key from command line. What's the command I can use?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, sftp

I am trying to connect to SFTP server with ssh key. I can't use FileZilla because we have an additional layer of security which doesn't allow me to use Filezilla. I have copied the ssh key over the server. I have the username and sftp server hostname. I tried finding a command which I can use but haven't been able to find it. I found a link where they said to copy the ssh key in the .ssh folder in the authorized_keys file but I remember not having to do this previously.

Could you guys help?

Comment: Do you mean `ssh-copy-id` ?

Comment: FileZilla wouldn't have helped anyway, it doesn't support sftp (in the sense of ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the client is linux,

the regular openssh sftp client picks up the private key if it's in the regular location ~/.ssh/id_rsa

If the private key is in non default place use -i <identity_file_pathname>  ( man sftp )

Permissions and ownership matter in both ends, both directories and files ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

try verbose logging with sftp -v or sftp -vvvv and check if either file is rejected because of file or directory user/group ownership or permissions.

It is also possible the server has disabled private key login. Check logging.